# How to turn my drag and drop into a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a drag and drop game that I am now considering changing.

Basically there is a grid with words in and the word to be spelt is highlighted. Usually you would drag and drop the letters to complete the word, but I am now thinking of making it so the user clicks the letters and they appear in the highlighted area.

Here is the script for it....

```
$('#pickNext').click(function() {
// remove the class from all td's
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
// pick a random word
rndWord = shuffledWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.8 - Math.random();
})[0];
// apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
$('td[data-word="' + rndWord + '"]').addClass('spellword');
});



$('.drag').draggable({

helper: 'clone',
snap: '.drop',
grid: [60, 60],
revert: function(droppable) {
    if (droppable === false) {
        return true;
    }

    else {

        return false;
    }
}
});


$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
    console.log($(event));
    console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

        $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('wordglow');
    }
    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass('wordglow2');

        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
            guesses[word].splice(0, guesses[word].length);
        }
    }






},

activate: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    // try to remove the class
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3');
}


});
```

How would I go about changing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid to say due to the massive change in the code structure, your probably better off starting this part from scratch

http://weepy.github.com/jquery.path/

Try these examples, good luck.